# Terraform plan - Error: Failed to load config

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I have problem with running terraform plan:

Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable

Error: Failed to load config (/Users/holodar/.kube/config; default context): invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided*

on providers.tf line 7, in provider "kubernetes":

7: provider "kubernetes" {

The config file exists in this localization.
The providers.tf contains:
...

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  version = "~> 1.9.0"
}
```

...

I used:
Terraform v0.12.26

- provider.datadog v2.25.0
- provider.google v3.65.0
- provider.helm v1.0.0
- provider.kubernetes v1.9.0
- provider.null v2.1.2
- provider.random v2.3.1
- provider.template v2.2.0
- provider.vault v2.19.1

Comment: Both Terraform 0.12 and the Kubernetes provider 1.9 are quite old versions. Have you thought about getting the latest releases?

Comment: what does the command `kubectl config get-contexts` display? From the error it appears you have no kubectl config to connect too.